# Java insert LinkedList into existing LinkedList

Tags: java, insert

I am writing a class that reads an XML file, the XML is parsed with 'sax' classes.  In my XML file I have create 'for' tags and 'macros' that enable for loops to be written in the XML for example:

```
    <for start="1" end="10" iterator="row" increment="1">
      <text>This is line $row$</text>
    </for>
```

The text $row$ is replaced at run time with the value of the iterator.  When the for loop is processed it generates a macro called 'row' that is used to process the loop content.  This works well.

My XML parser generates a LinkedList of tag classes where each tag contains its own LinkedList of child tags.

The 'for' loop is a tag, when the 'for' loop is processed it generates a LinkedList of results.  I want to replace the original 'for' tag in the LinkedList with the generated LinkedList.

Comment: I find it rather hard to follow your question. Can you provide some example code? Inserting/merging lists is quite easy to do but I have the feeling you're after something else.

Comment: What you're probably after is the `addAll(int, Collection<E>)` method, e.g. something like 1st remove the for tag and 2nd add all text tags at the former index of the for tag.

Comment: Thank you, I found this shortly after posting and am investigating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

On original linked list, find the object to be removed:

```
    intForIdx = llChildren.indexOf(mobjCurrent);
```

Remove the original object:

```
    llChildren.remove(intForIdx);
```

Insert the new linked list at the same location:

```
    llChildren.addAll(intForIdx, llResults);
```